# Terminal outputs 'command not found' after installing python 3.7.1

Tags: python, macos, terminal, installation

I want to start learning Django, so the first step is to install python. I downloaded python and wanted to test that it is really installed by using the terminal. I typed `python` and `python --v` and `python --version` but everytime the terminal says

> -bash: python: command not found

I have been looking online for solutions but none have been helpful so far. Even when I type `ls` it says

> -bash: ls: command not found

I tried resetting the terminal but that didn't change anything.

Apologies if this is a very simple question to ask, but after trying for about an hour, I'm not sure where else to turn. Thanks.

---

UPDATE: Typing

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

enabled me to get a different output. When i typed ls after that it worked as expected, and when i typed python it says:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

Now I just need to figure out why it isn't python 3.7.1!

Comment: Your environment is really screwed if it can't even find `ls`. Any chance you can reinstall the OS from scratch or describe who had been using or what have you been doing with the system?

Comment: Yeah maybe it is a victim of my poor programming skills a few years ago when I played around on terminal... I could do a 'hard reset'? I can only navigate around if i type export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH  everytime i open terminal

Comment: Three suggestions. 1. Start terminal, open Terminal Preferences.  Select General (at the top). Check the "Shells open with:" is set to Default login shell.   See if that at least gets you going with simple unix commands like "ls".   2. I suggest navigate under the OSX GUI to see where your python 2.7.10 and 3. 7.1 are installed and check with typical locations they should be found with standard install. Perhaps in past play you moved things around. 3. Adding by what means you installed Python 3.7.1 in the body of your question might help others identify the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly I never had a mac OS but I guess you did not added the Python path to your environment.

Please read it:

https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/